# Add text to matched pattern in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to add text whenever I see an "struct" definition with partial matching here. Each structure can have another structs as it members, I only ned to add 'typedef' to the outer/main struct line.

```
struct struct-A {
...
struct struct-B;
};
```

to

```
typedef struct struct-A {
...
struct struct-B;
};
```

Comment: Are the `struct` members like `struct-B` not indented?

Comment: Indentation of fields is optional.

Comment: Is the `{` always on the same line as `struct` for the outer structure definitions?

Comment: Yes, it is the same

Comment: While it would be fairly trivial to construct a regex to add `typedef` as you are suggesting (`perl -p -i -e 's/(struct .*{)/typedef $1/' *.[ch]`), it wouldn't accomplish your goal, since you actually need to specify the name of the `typedef` after your closing `};`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed '/;[[:blank:]]*$/!s/^[[:blank:]]*struct/typedef &/' file

typedef struct struct-A {
   ...
   struct struct-B;
};
```

This `sed` command checks for existence of `;` at end of line and only when it is not present it adds `typedef` before `struct` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check on below `sed` -

`sed '/;/! s/struct\ struct-/typedef\ struct\ struct-/g' file`

```
typedef struct struct-A {
...
struct struct-B;
};
typedef struct struct-C {
...
struct struct-D;
};
```

This sed will replace `struct` with `typedef struct` when it won't find `;` in the line.